# Android Bluetooth device obtained using getRemoteDevice() from a connected socket has a null name and a reversed Mac address

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

Please see the below java code together with the screenshots from the debugger.
**Details:**
The mmSocket is a bluetooth connected socket obtained using 
mmServerSocket.accept(), when mmServerSocket obtained by
listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord().
There is only one paired device called "samsung" (mmSocket represents a connection to it)
**The problem is:**
I'm unable to fetch the remote connected device's name and address through the socket;
mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress() returns a reversed mac address and
mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().getName() returns a null.
although, I'm able to do so on the paired device.
How can I get the name of a remote device from a connected socket like mmSocket ?
Thanks

```
            String addrThroughSocket = mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
            String nameThroughSocket = mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
            String addrThroughPairedDevices = null;
            String nameThroughPairedDevices = null;
            int pairedSize = 0;             
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
            pairedSize = pairedDevices.size();              
            if (pairedSize > 0)
            {
                for(BluetoothDevice d : pairedDevices)
                {
                    addrThroughPairedDevices = d.getAddress().toString();
                    nameThroughPairedDevices = d.getName();
                    device1 = d;                            
                }
            }
```

Screenshot 1 : the variables values while running the debugger
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WQH0.jpg 
Screenshot 2 : the code screenshot while running the debugger
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AKjf.jpg

Comment: Looking at your code, you call toString() on getAddress() on the Paired device, but just use the string returned by getAddress on the remote device from the socket. I'm betting that's the source of your discrepancy on the mac address.

As for the name, getName() returns the cached name. Perhaps the name hasn't been cached at the point in the code. What happens if you try getting the same through the socket after you successfully read it through the bonded device list?

Comment: All this code comes after reading/writing from/to the sucket. the toString has no effect.

Comment: I doubt it's a caching issue because of the reversed mac address. currently, the ugly workaround that i use is:  device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(my_custom_reverse_mac(mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress()))  for example my_custom_reverse_mac("12:34:56:78:90:ab") returns "ab:90:78:56:34:12"

Comment: So you've removed the toString() call and verified that the mac address still gets reversed?

Comment: the toString() is not the problem. yes i removed it. addrThroughPairedDevices has the correct value.